# Keras convolution2d error

Tags: keras

Grayscale images (width 12px, height 12px) are processed in training and test as below code in Keras.

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1,12,12)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), border_mode=("same")))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

However, error happens as below.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,12,32], [3,3,32,32].
```

Let me know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I was doing object detection and the problem I figured out was with some corrupt images. When keras tries to read images but being corrupt the image is not loaded. So instead of throwing an error for image it starts performing operation and fails. So just check if you can successfully load images before starting model training. This will give you the culprit files. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keras expects the format like this : (samples, rows, cols, channels), your format seems to be (samples, channels, rows, cols).

Try specifying the data format with the optional parameter data_format, like so:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1,12,12), data_format = 'channels_first'))
```